# minItems doesn't seem to validate correctly in JSON schema

Tags: arrays, json, validation, jsonschema

I'm writing a simple JSON schema and using `minItems` to validate the number of items in a given array. My schema is as follows:

```
{
"title": "My Schema",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "root": {
        "type": "array",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "myarray": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "minItems": 4,
                "uniqueItems": true
            },
            "boolean": {
                "type": "boolean"
            }
        },
        "required": ["id","myarray","boolean"]
    }
},
"required": [
    "root"
],
"additionalProperties": false
}
```

Now I would expect the following JSON to fail validation given the element `myarray` has nothing in it. But when using [this online validator](http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/), it passes. Have I done something wrong or is the schema validator I'm using faulty?

```
{
"root":[
    {
        "id":"1234567890",
        "myarray":[],
        "boolean":true
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why or what it is called, but the correct schema definition for your requirement should be as shown further down.

From what I understand from the JSON Schema definitions, you should declare the properties of an array inside the items declaration. In your schema you where defining properties outside of the array item declaration.

In your schema you have the two different types of array declaration:

- Once with just a single object (a string for the "myarray" object)
- Once with a complex object (the object name "myComplexType" in the code below)

Have a look at the definitions of both, how they are structured and how they would be interpreted.

The corrected schema:

```
{
  "title": "My Schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "root": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {                  <-- Difference here - "items" instead of "properties"
        "type": "object",         <-- here - define the array items as a complex object
        "title": "myComplexType", <-- here - named for easier referencing
        "properties": {           <-- and here - now we can define the actual properties of the object
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "myarray": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "minItems": 4,
            "uniqueItems": true
          },
          "boolean": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "id",
        "myarray",
        "boolean"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "root"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Remove the comments I added with `<--` when copying over to your code, added for pointing where there changes are.

As a note, I do however don't understand why the validator didn't give an error for the 'malformed' schema, but might just be that it saw the definition as you had it as additional properties, not entirely sure.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. As for your final comment - it may be that the validator just ensures it's valid JSON rather than a valid JSON schema, who knows...

Answer (score 1):

The only thing wrong with your schema is that the `root` property should have type `object` instead of `array`.  Because the `properties` keyword is not defined for arrays, it is ignored.  Therefore, the part of the schema you were trying to test was completely ignored even though it was correct.

Here is the relevant passage from the specification

> Some validation keywords only apply to one or more primitive types. When the primitive type of the instance cannot be validated by a given keyword, validation for this keyword and instance SHOULD succeed.
>
> - http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.4.1